# How to get only a few fields that we need from a JSON in JAVA

Tags: java

Is it possible to get only a few fields from a JSON while converting to java using gson. Below is the sample data. Out of the below data I need only id, `this_account.id`, `details.value.amount`, `details.type`. How can I achieve this? I'm using gson to convert it. Should I create classes for unnecessary objects here? I seem to need only this, this_account, other_account and details here.

```
"transactions":[
      {
         "id":"dcb8138c-eb88-404a-981d-d4edff1086a6",
         "this_account":{
            "id":"savings-kids-john",
            "holders":[
               {
                  "name":"Savings - Kids John",
                  "is_alias":false
               }
            ],
            "number":"832425-00304050",
            "kind":"savings",
            "IBAN":null,
            "swift_bic":null,
            "bank":{
               "national_identifier":"rbs",
               "name":"The Royal Bank of Scotland"
            }
         },
         "other_account":{
            "id":"c83f9a12-171e-4602-9a92-ae895c41b16b",
            "holder":{
               "name":"ALIAS_CBCDE5",
               "is_alias":true
            },
            "number":"13677980653",
            "kind":"CURRENT PLUS",
            "IBAN":"BA12 1234 5123 4513 6779 8065 377",
            "swift_bic":null,
            "bank":{
               "national_identifier":null,
               "name":"The Bank of X"
            },
            "metadata":{
               "public_alias":null,
               "private_alias":null,
               "more_info":null,
               "URL":null,
               "image_URL":null,
               "open_corporates_URL":null,
               "corporate_location":null,
               "physical_location":null
            }
         },
         "details":{
            "type":"sandbox-payment",
            "description":"Description abc",
            "posted":"2016-10-09T20:01:53Z",
            "completed":"2016-10-09T20:01:53Z",
            "new_balance":{
               "currency":"GBP",
               "amount":null
            },
            "value":{
               "currency":"GBP",
               "amount":"10.00"
            }
         },
         "metadata":{
            "narrative":null,
            "comments":[

            ],
            "tags":[

            ],
            "images":[

            ],
            "where":null
         }
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JsonObject.remove("field_name");` to remove a unwanted element.
For example:

if you have json:

```
{
  "name":"ratul",
  "id":"1"
}
```

and you want to remove the name.Then do this.

```
JsonObject j = new JsonObject(jsonString);
j.remove("name");
```

The output will be:

```
{
  "id":"1"
}
```

Comment: Ok, here transactions is a list. How can I populate it using gson